# Puppet user manifest does any effect on puppetclient

Tags: ruby, puppet

On VirtualBox I have 2 servers:

1)hostname: puppetmaster 192.168.100.8

2)hostname: pupetclient 192.168.100.9

on both servers puppet is running

I used docu from ubuntu to install it:

https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/tools-puppet

servers are ubuntu 20.04

I run pupetclient and master noticed certificate and I signed it

servers can ping each other.

Master:

```
cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   puppetmaster.example.com    puppetmaster
192.168.100.9   puppetclient.example.com puppetclient
```

Client:

```
cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   puppetclient.example.com    puppetclient
192.168.100.8 puppetmaster.example.com puppetmaster puppet
```

At the begining I created the simples code to create a user:

```
root@puppetmaster:/etc/puppet/code/environments# cd ../../
root@puppetmaster:/etc/puppet# tree
.
|-- auth.conf
|-- code
|   `-- environments
|       `-- production
|           `-- modules
|               |-- mymodule
|               |   |-- files
|               |   |   `-- test.txt
|               |   `-- manifests
|               |       |-- init.pp
|               |       `-- site.pp
|               `-- user
|                   `-- manifests
|                       |-- init.pp
|                       `-- site.pp
|-- hiera.yaml
`-- puppet.conf

cat puppet.conf 
[main]
ssldir = /var/lib/puppet/ssl

[master]
vardir = /var/lib/puppet
cadir  = /var/lib/puppet/ssl/ca
dns_alt_names = puppet

cat code/environments/production/modules/user/manifests/init.pp 
class user {
  user { 'testuser123':
    ensure => present,
    comment => 'bogo user',
    home => '/home/testuser123',
    managehome => true
  }
}

root@puppetmaster:/etc/puppet# cat code/environments/production/modules/user/manifests/site.pp 
node 'puppetclient.example.com' {
  include user
}

sudo puppet apply /etc/puppet/code/environments/production/modules/user/manifests/init.pp 
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/util.rb:461: warning: URI.escape is obsolete
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/util.rb:461: warning: URI.escape is obsolete
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/util.rb:461: warning: URI.escape is obsolete
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/util.rb:461: warning: URI.escape is obsolete
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/util.rb:315: warning: deprecated Object#=~ is called on Puppet::Transaction::Report; it always returns nil
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/util.rb:461: warning: URI.escape is obsolete
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/util.rb:461: warning: URI.escape is obsolete
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/util.rb:461: warning: URI.escape is obsolete
Notice: Compiled catalog for puppetmaster.example.com in environment production in 0.01 seconds
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/util.rb:461: warning: URI.escape is obsolete
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/util.rb:461: warning: URI.escape is obsolete
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/util.rb:315: warning: deprecated Object#=~ is called on Puppet::Transaction::Report; it always returns nil
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/file_system/uniquefile.rb:126: warning: $SAFE will become a normal global variable in Ruby 3.0
Notice: Applied catalog in 0.01 seconds
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/file_system/uniquefile.rb:126: warning: $SAFE will become a normal global variable in Ruby 3.0
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/util.rb:315: warning: deprecated Object#=~ is called on Puppet::Transaction::Report; it always returns nil
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/file_system/uniquefile.rb:126: warning: $SAFE will become a normal global variable in Ruby 3.0
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/file_system/uniquefile.rb:126: warning: $SAFE will become a normal global variable in Ruby 3.0

user@puppetclient:/home$ sudo puppet agent --test
[sudo] password for user: 
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/util.rb:461: warning: URI.escape is obsolete
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/util.rb:461: warning: URI.escape is obsolete
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/util.rb:461: warning: URI.escape is obsolete
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/util.rb:461: warning: URI.escape is obsolete
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/util.rb:315: warning: deprecated Object#=~ is called on Puppet::Transaction::Report; it always returns nil
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/util.rb:461: warning: URI.escape is obsolete
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/util.rb:461: warning: URI.escape is obsolete
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/util.rb:461: warning: URI.escape is obsolete
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/util.rb:315: warning: deprecated Object#=~ is called on Puppet::Transaction::Report; it always returns nil
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/util.rb:461: warning: URI.escape is obsolete
Info: Using configured environment 'production'
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/util.rb:461: warning: URI.escape is obsolete
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/util.rb:315: warning: deprecated Object#=~ is called on Puppet::Transaction::Report; it always returns nil
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/util.rb:461: warning: URI.escape is obsolete
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/indirector/request.rb:272: warning: URI.unescape is obsolete
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/util.rb:461: warning: URI.escape is obsolete
Info: Retrieving plugin
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/util.rb:461: warning: URI.escape is obsolete
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/util.rb:315: warning: deprecated Object#=~ is called on Puppet::Transaction::Report; it always returns nil
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/util.rb:461: warning: URI.escape is obsolete
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/indirector/request.rb:272: warning: URI.unescape is obsolete
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/util.rb:461: warning: URI.escape is obsolete
Info: Retrieving locales
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/util.rb:461: warning: URI.escape is obsolete
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/util.rb:315: warning: deprecated Object#=~ is called on Puppet::Transaction::Report; it always returns nil
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/util.rb:461: warning: URI.escape is obsolete
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/indirector/request.rb:272: warning: URI.unescape is obsolete
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/util.rb:461: warning: URI.escape is obsolete
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/util.rb:461: warning: URI.escape is obsolete
Info: Caching catalog for puppetclient.example.com
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/file_system/uniquefile.rb:126: warning: $SAFE will become a normal global variable in Ruby 3.0
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/util.rb:461: warning: URI.escape is obsolete
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/util.rb:461: warning: URI.escape is obsolete
Info: Applying configuration version '1694262084'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/file_system/uniquefile.rb:126: warning: $SAFE will become a normal global variable in Ruby 3.0
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/file_system/uniquefile.rb:126: warning: $SAFE will become a normal global variable in Ruby 3.0
Notice: Applied catalog in 0.01 seconds
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/file_system/uniquefile.rb:126: warning: $SAFE will become a normal global variable in Ruby 3.0
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/util.rb:461: warning: URI.escape is obsolete
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/file_system/uniquefile.rb:126: warning: $SAFE will become a normal global variable in Ruby 3.0
```

**and it is nothing, where is error? On puppetclient server there is no new user :(**

Answer (score 0):

> **where is error? On puppetclient server there is no new user**

Based on its name and the fact that it contains a node declaration, you seem to intend `/etc/puppet/code/environments/production/modules/user/manifests/site.pp` to be a site manifest.  It is not one.  Nor is `/etc/puppet/code/environments/production/modules/mymodule/manifests/site.pp`

By default, the starting point for catalog compilation for a given environment -- that is, its site manifest -- is the collection of manifest files residing directly in the `manifests/` folder of the environment itself.  In your case, that would be `/etc/puppet/code/environments/production/manifests`, which you do not show even existing.  Create that folder, making sure that it has correct permissions, and move the contents of your two `site.pp` files there. (You probably want to merge them into one file.)